# java- repeatedly getting errors when I repeatedly use an element and then update that key's value, into a hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I am working on an application in which a repetitive programming task is performed.

As part of this task, a value is assigned to a variable, then this variable is inserted into the hashmap, used in some operations and then the value in hashmap is replaced with a new value from the same variable.

What I mean is, after first value is used up, another value is assigned to the same variable-> variable is inserted into the hashmap->value fetched from hashmap for use in an operation->and so on.

In this way many values are being added->used->updatedfrom hashmap. This is all happening in a while loop which also has a counter variable.

The problem is that at random stages of the while loop all of a sudden an error is thrown that the hashmap does not contain an object with specified key.

This never occurs at the same counter number of while loop...What am I doing wrong here? Is this happening because of my repeatedly inserting->using->updating values into the hashmap?

For your ref, the code to insert data into the hashmap is given below--

```
   /* Function to store a variable- key value pair at designated level, in scraper context..
  *
  */
 public Object putVar(Object key, Variable value, Integer level) {
    super.put((this.getStringKey(key)+"~"+level.toString()), value);
    return null;
 }
```

The code to get data from the hashmap is given below--

```
 /* Function to obtain object (value) with specified key and level in scraper context...
 *
 */
public Object get(Object key, Integer level) {

    String req= this.getStringKey(key);
    boolean found=false;
    System.out.println(" REQUIRED- Variable name="+ req + "level="+ level);
    for(int i= level; i>=1; i--)
    {
        if(this.containsKey(req+"~"+level.toString()) )
        {
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found==true)
        return(this.get(req+"~"+level.toString()));
    else
        return null;
}
```

UPDATE- The exception stack trace is given below---

```
 ERROR - Variable 'webpage' is not defined!
 org.webharvest.exception.VariableException: Variable 'webpage' is not defined!
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.VarProcessor.execute(VarProcessor.java:70)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:119)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:28)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.getBodyTextContent(BaseProcessor.java:176)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.getBodyTextContent(BaseProcessor.java:184)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.getBodyTextContent(BaseProcessor.java:188)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.FileProcessor.executeFileWrite(FileProcessor.java:146)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.FileProcessor.execute(FileProcessor.java:95)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:119)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BodyProcessor.execute(BodyProcessor.java:28)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.WhileProcessor.execute(WhileProcessor.java:112)
at org.webharvest.runtime.processors.BaseProcessor.run(BaseProcessor.java:119)
at org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:179)
at org.webharvest.runtime.Scraper.execute(Scraper.java:195)
at org.webharvest.gui.ScraperExecutionThread.run(ScraperExecutionThread.java:56)
```

Finally, the relevant code that throws this exception is given below--the name of the hashmap being used is 'context'

```
Variable var = (Variable) context.get(name, curr_level);
 if (var == null) {
        throw new VariableException("Variable '" + name + "' is not defined!");
    }
```

Comment: What line throws exception? And could you show your loop where you insert/update/delete values?

Comment: Can you please share the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Your `get` does not the same as your `put`: `put` honours the value of `level`. your `get` does some iteration but the iteration variable `i` is *not* use anywhere. All accesses to the hashmap in `get` are using the same fixed value of `level`.

This seems more than dubious to me.

Comment: if a variable has var.name=x and level=1, then its key in the hashmap is "x~1" and the get checks for the variable of same name starting from highest numerical level upto 1, which is the lowest level...for eg it first checks for "x~3" if this is not found it checks for "x~2" and finally it checks for "x~1" ... that is why that code is not like the put...

Comment: @Arvind Try to replace `for(int i= level; i>=1; i--)` with `for(; level>=1; level--)`

Comment: @Arvind: That's perhaps what you think it does. But it does not. Each lookup in the map will always use the same value for `level`. So in level 3 you say `this.contains("mykey~3")` three times.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you return the value, at the level, that you find:

i.e. you need to change your `get` method slightly:

```
/**
 * Function to obtain object (value) with specified key and level in scraper context
 * i.e. if a value is not found for the key at the given level, lower levels will
 * be searched.
 */
public Object get(Object key, Integer level) {
    String req= this.getStringKey(key);
    System.out.println(" REQUIRED- Variable name="+ req + "level="+ level);
    for(int i= level; i>=1; i--) {
        if(this.containsKey(req + "~" + i) ) {
            return(this.get(req + "~" + i));
        }
    }
    return null; //or, throw your exception here to differentiate between
                 //finding a null value and not finding the key at all
}
```

At present you only check for, and return, the value for the key `req+"~"+level.toString()`. You might also consider adding a bit more information to your exception, such as the level at which the `get` fails at.

Comment: i made the changes you have said, you are correct in your answer, however i am still getting the same error message?

Comment: do you ever put in a null value? try throwing an exception in the `get` method if none of the keys are found - at least to see exactly where the problem arises.